# Remove hacks from my odata generic base Controller?

Tags: c#, generics, odata

I have created this GenericController to move all CRUD logics to GenericController, and I hacked some stuff to make it work like:

1. Create TableForT to set the entity
2. Create interface IndexedModel to hold GUID to make Compraion
3. hard code the DB context

How can I remove those hacks from my code to keep my code clean?

```
namespace AirVinyl.API.Controllers
{
    public class GenericController<T> : ODataController where T : class, IndexedModel
    {
        AirVinylDbContext db = new AirVinylDbContext();

        private bool Exists(long key)
        {
            return TableForT().Any(p => p.Id.Equals(key));
        }

        private DbSet<T> TableForT()
        {
            return db.Set<T>();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [EnableQuery] // EnableQuery allows filter, sort, page, top, etc.
        public IQueryable<T> Get()
        {
            return TableForT();
        }


        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<T> Get([FromODataUri] long key)
        {
            IQueryable<T> result = Get().Where(p => p.Id.Equals(key));
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }


        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(T obj)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            TableForT().Add(obj);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(obj);
        }


        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] long key, Delta<T> delta)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var entity = await TableForT().FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            delta.Patch(entity);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!Exists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Updated(entity);
        }


        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] long key, T obj)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (key.Equals(obj.Id) == false)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!Exists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Updated(obj);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] long key)
        {
            var entity = await TableForT().FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            TableForT().Remove(entity);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long research and reading

```
  public class GenericController<T> : ODataController where T : class, IndexedModel
    {

        private readonly AirVinylDbContext db;
        private readonly DbSet<T> set;

        public GenericController()
        {
            this.db = new AirVinylDbContext();
            this.set = this.db.Set<T>();
        }
        private bool Exists(Guid key)
        {
            return this.set.Any(p => p.Id.Equals(key));
        }



        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [EnableQuery] // EnableQuery allows filter, sort, page, top, etc.
        public IQueryable<T> Get()
        {
            return this.set.AsQueryable();
        }


        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<T> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            IQueryable<T> result = Get().Where(p => p.Id.Equals(key));
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }


        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(T obj)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            this.set.Add(obj);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(obj);
        }


        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] Guid key, Delta<T> delta)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var entity = await this.set.FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            delta.Patch(entity);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!Exists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Updated(entity);
        }


        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] Guid key, T obj)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (key.Equals(obj.Id) == false)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!Exists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Updated(obj);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            var entity = await this.set.FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            this.set.Remove(entity);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
}
```